# No display changes from hook_menu_get_item_alter()

Tags: routes

I have a string of subsites that need very special menu handling, beyond the normal menu router capabilities. I need to decide in real time (absolutely real time, thus no way to store it in the menu_router table) which menu items I want to display. The obvious solution would be to hook into hook_menu_get_item_alter(). That's what I do, setting $router_item['access_callback'] = FALSE for all menu items I want to suppress. When checked after hook_menu_get_item_alter(), they get changed all right. However, by the time they reach the display stage in theme_menu_link(), all access variables are reverted to TRUE, thus all menu items appear all right. Drupal 7.25.

Any ideas?

Addendum: hook_node_access() is out of question for two reasons: views should be handled as well and user #1 should see the same results as anybody else.

Thanks,
Gábor